# Slicing pandas groupby groups into equal lengths

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas groupby data frame that looks like the below and is grouped on `page`:

```
+---------+------+-------+
|  page   | hour | count |
+---------+------+-------+
| 3727441 |    1 |  2003 |
| 3727441 |    2 |   654 |
| 3727441 |    3 |  5434 |
| 3727458 |    1 |   326 |
| 3727458 |    2 |  2348 |
| 3727458 |    3 |  4040 |
| 3727458 |    4 |   374 |
| 3727458 |    5 |  2917 |
| 3727458 |    6 |  3937 |
| 3735634 |    1 |  1957 |
| 3735634 |    2 |  2398 |
| 3735634 |    3 |  2812 |
| 3768433 |    1 |   499 |
| 3768433 |    2 |  4924 |
| 3768433 |    3 |  5460 |
| 3768433 |    4 |  1710 |
| 3768433 |    5 |  3877 |
| 3768433 |    6 |  1912 |
| 3768433 |    7 |  1367 |
| 3768433 |    8 |  1626 |
| 3768433 |    9 |  4750 |
+---------+------+-------+
```

You will notice that some of the groups have 3, 6 or 9 rows as counted by the hours.  What I would like to do is slice each group down to 3 hours max and append something to the 6 and 9 length groups to denote that it is the same page like the following:

```
+-----------+------+-------+
|   page    | hour | count |
+-----------+------+-------+
| 3727441   |    1 |  2003 |
| 3727441   |    2 |   654 |
| 3727441   |    3 |  5434 |
| 3727458   |    1 |   326 |
| 3727458   |    2 |  2348 |
| 3727458   |    3 |  4040 |
| 3727458_1 |    4 |   374 |
| 3727458_1 |    5 |  2917 |
| 3727458_1 |    6 |  3937 |
| 3735634   |    1 |  1957 |
| 3735634   |    2 |  2398 |
| 3735634   |    3 |  2812 |
| 3768433   |    1 |   499 |
| 3768433   |    2 |  4924 |
| 3768433   |    3 |  5460 |
| 3768433_1 |    4 |  1710 |
| 3768433_1 |    5 |  3877 |
| 3768433_1 |    6 |  1912 |
| 3768433_2 |    7 |  1367 |
| 3768433_2 |    8 |  1626 |
| 3768433_2 |    9 |  4750 |
+-----------+------+-------+
```

I attempted to do begin doing this with `enumerate`:

```
for name, group in hourly_groups:
        for i, x in enumerate(group):
            print x
```

but it isn't returning the right groups.

Also tried this below:

```
for k, g in df_hourly.groupby(df_hourly['page'] - 3):
    print g
```

---

Edit:

I truncated, my data thinking that it would be easier to understand, but the solutions given seem to not work on my actual data set.  Here is a sample of the actual data set where page `3694750` is an example of a page that needs to be broken into groups of 34.  http://www.sharecsv.com/s/b2dbe8e49d6a2481de138f6ca06c679e/test.csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what you want, to use an df.apply method

```
import pandas as pd

cols = ['page', 'hour', 'count']
data = [
    (3727441,    1,  2003),
    (3727441,    2,   654),
    (3727441,    3,  5434),
    (3727458,    1,   326),
    (3727458,    2,  2348),
    (3727458,    3,  4040),
    (3727458,    4,   374),
    (3727458,    5,  2917),
    (3727458,    6,  3937),
    (3735634,    1,  1957),
    (3735634,    2,  2398),
    (3735634,    3,  2812),
    (3768433,    1,   499),
    (3768433,    2,  4924),
    (3768433,    3,  5460),
    (3768433,    4,  1710),
    (3768433,    5,  3877),
    (3768433,    6,  1912),
    (3768433,    7,  1367),
    (3768433,    8,  1626),
    (3768433,    9,  4750),
]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=cols)

def f(row):
    n = (row.hour - 1) / 3 
    if n > 0:
        return str(row.page) + '_{0}'.format(int(n))
    else:
        return row.page

df['page'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)

print df
```

Output:

```
 #       page  hour  count
 # 0     3727441     1   2003
 # 1     3727441     2    654
 # 2     3727441     3   5434
 # 3     3727458     1    326
 # 4     3727458     2   2348
 # 5     3727458     3   4040
 # 6   3727458_1     4    374
 # 7   3727458_1     5   2917
 # 8   3727458_1     6   3937
 # 9     3735634     1   1957
 # 10    3735634     2   2398
 # 11    3735634     3   2812
 # 12    3768433     1    499
 # 13    3768433     2   4924
 # 14    3768433     3   5460
 # 15  3768433_1     4   1710
 # 16  3768433_1     5   3877
 # 17  3768433_1     6   1912
 # 18  3768433_2     7   1367
 # 19  3768433_2     8   1626
 # 20  3768433_2     9   4750
```

Comment: If it's your `df` is a groupby object, you may want to convert multi-index to columns first with `df.reset_index(inplace=True)`

Comment: So, I truncated my data set in the question to make it easier to read and thinking that whatever solution came would also apply..  In actuality, the groupings are 34 rows long, and replacing the `3` with `34` does not seem to work - any thoughts?

Comment: Do you mean the 3 as in `n = (row.hour - 1) / 3`? 3 is the variable corresponding to your **slice each group down to 3 hours max** requirement. What do you mean by 34?

Comment: so each page has 34 hours of data, not 3 - if you see my edit in the question there is a link to a sample of the actual data set.  Yes, the corresponding slice is the 34 hours max requirement

Comment: I guess you didn't ask your question clearly. Do you mean you want to slice each group down to 34 hours max in the real dataset? 34 and 3 are not conceptually equivalent from my interpretation of your question. The corresponding number to 34 for your toy example is more likely to be 6 or 9

Comment: Yes, apologies. I really didn't articulate as well as I should have. Yes I want to slice each group down to 34 hours max in the real data set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88403/discussion-between-zyxue-and-meter).

Answer (score 2):

How about just integer division with `//` operator?

```
In [164]:

df.page.astype(str)+np.where(df.hour>3, 
                             '_'+((df.hour.astype(int)-1)//3).astype(str),
                             '')
#overwrite df['page'] with this
Out[164]:
0       3727441
1       3727441
2       3727441
3       3727458
4       3727458
5       3727458
6     3727458_1
7     3727458_1
8     3727458_1
9       3735634
10      3735634
11      3735634
12      3768433
13      3768433
14      3768433
15    3768433_1
16    3768433_1
17    3768433_1
18    3768433_2
19    3768433_2
20    3768433_2
Name: page, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you want to relabel your index on a groupby result (I'll assume it is named `hourly_groups')

```
hourly_groups.reset_index(inplace=True)
hourly_groups['page'] = hourly_groups.page.apply(lambda x: str(x)) + hourly_groups.hour.apply(lambda x: '_1' if 3 < x <= 6 else ('_2' if x > 6 else ""))
hourly_groups.set_index(['page', 'hour'], inplace=True)

>>> hourly_groups
                count
page      hour       
3727441   1      2003
          2       654
          3      5434
3727458   1       326
          2      2348
          3      4040
3727458_1 4       374
          5      2917
          6      3937
3735634   1      1957
          2      2398
          3      2812
3768433   1       499
          2      4924
          3      5460
3768433_1 4      1710
          5      3877
          6      1912
3768433_2 7      1367
          8      1626
          9      4750
```